# Cannot delete skill

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant-solutions

I cannot delete a skill from the Skills tab.
The checkboxes to select the skill (pre-existing or added by me) are disabled. 
Is it a bug or I am missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's functionality that hasn't been added yet.  We are still working on flushing out this UI.  For now you will have to use the Swagger UI to do this.  Click on the Conversation API link from the Console page and use the DELETE /v2/api/skills/{skillName}
Remove a skill API.